# Handling async events in javascript classes / libs without bind

Tags: javascript, class, xmlhttprequest, bind

so this is my code

```
function dl(name){
 this.name=name;
 this.getInfo();
};
dl.prototype={
 getInfo:function(){
  this.x=new XMLHttpRequest;
  this.x.open('GET',this.name);
  this.bind=this.setInfo.bind(this);
  this.x.addEventListener('load',this.bind,false);
  this.x.send();
 },
 setInfo:function(){
  this.info=this.x.response;
  this.x.removeEventListener('load',this.bind,false);
  delete this.bind;
  delete this.x;
  this.insertDOM();
 }
};
```

I use `function dl(){}` approach because i want to have access to everything with `this`.

I use `prototype` because when i create many `new dl(SOMEURL)` it won't touch the memory.

But yeah as it has many xhr2 functions inside i need to find the best way to return everything correctly.

So using xhr2 normally is wonderfull...

```
function ajax(a,b,c){ //url,function,placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;c.open('GET',a);c.onload=b;c.send();
}    
//example onload function    
function b(){ //don't even need event....
 console.log(this.response)
}
```

Good: i pass only the function reference (no arguments,no strange that,me vars..)

Bad: in a class i loose the `this` pointer to my class

so i started with defining the xhr object inside my class

```
this.x=new XMLHttpRequest;
```

and used `bind` to pass this on my next function this.setInfo

but to remove the eventlistener later i need to define a new variable that contains the binded function.

```
this.bind=this.setInfo.bind(this);
```

and i really hate that.(i'm trying to use as many variables as possible and using low memory)

i don't even know if this really removes the event.

other solution i'm thinking of is to refer the this to the xhr2 object.

```
function dl(name){
 this.name=name;
 this.getInfo(this.name);
};
dl.prototype={
 getInfo:function(){
  var x=new XMLHttpRequest;
  x.that=this;
  x.open('GET',this.name);
  x.addEventListener('load',this.setInfo,false);
  x.send();
 },
 setInfo:function(){
  this.that.info=this.response;
  this.removeEventListener('load',this.setInfo,false);
  this.that.insertDOM();
  delete this.that;
 }
};
```

**A.** *is `this.that` only a reference or does it fill the memory?*

i need to be shure that after each of this functions i delete/clear every var that i don't need anymore to help the garbage collector.

**B.** *Are there any better solutions in writing this type of javascript class??*

ps.:is there a more elegant wayto init the first function inside dl?

---

**What is this class for??**

it's a download manager for chrome

**How it works??**

i put a download link into a `input` field

the class adds a `new dl(SOMEURL)` to an array

retrieves the file info with a php cUrl script.

stores the file info inside the class

and executes another xhr with retrieves the first chunk of the file based on it's size.

the chunk will be appended to a `window.webkitrequestfilesystem` file previously created.

then it continues to loop over xhr requests until all chunks are downloaded and appended to the filesystem.

Saving the file offset status into `window.LocalStorage` gives me the opportunity to resume downloads later.

Comment: There are a lot of incorrect assumptions throughout this long question; it's very challenging to answer for that reason.

Comment: cool if you have an answer... what you mean with incorrect assumtions? my english is very bad.. sry

Comment: i also could not find the right title to explain what i mean... the point is to create a lib (function(){})() which does not have problems with other libs and to have full access to every event and variable inside that.but a big problem is a function which does not return the this pointer

Comment: There's no need to remove an event listener from an XHR object.  The garbage collector will figure out how to reclaim that. In general, it's not really worth your time to out-guess what the garbage collector needs until you actually start running into memory problems.

Comment: if i create the xhr object and define inside the this referrer... what happens to the garbade collector? like in solution 2

Comment: You really don't need to attach the XHR object to your "dl" object either, since the browser passes it back to the "readystatechange" event handler anyway.

Comment: look solution 2. Anyway in the solution 1 i get rid of it manually (theoretically) deleting it.

Comment: You don't even need to do that. The garbage collector can track when objects become unreferenced.

Comment: but there is a reference inside... ??? this.that

Comment: You don't need `this.that` because the browser will pass in the XHR object to your event handler.

Comment: i can't access 'that' (the new dl() this) inside the setInfo function... setInfo returns the xhr object and not the dl function.

Comment: Answer to question A: yes, you create a reference to `this` not a copy of `this` Answer to question B: I think you're save with the first solution or creating a closure as in user18... answer `x.onreadystatechange=function...`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've got the script to work, but I changed a few things. Firstly, I took put x.that and replaced it with a local variable (instance) that can be used inside onreadystatechange events. Secondly I added an onreadystatechange event, allows you to run a function when the ajax request loads, I  also modified the event listeners so that they would work, but I recommend using the onreadystatechange. Thirdly, I added a few things to test and the code works on Chrome. Finally, I changed setInfo so that it would take the response of the ajax request as a parameter. I think that's everything I did, so heres the code:

```
function dl(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.getInfo(this.name);
};
dl.prototype = {
    getInfo:function(){
        var instance = this;
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', this.name, false);

        // onreadystatechange event
        x.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(x.readyState == 4){
                if(x.status == 200){
                    instance.setInfo(x.responseText);
                } else {
                    /*
                        there was a network failure 
                        (File Not Found, Internal Server Error ...)
                    */
                }
            }
        }

        // if you really want to use event the listeners you had previously:
        this.request = x;
        x.addEventListener('load', function(){
            instance.setInfo(x.responseText);
        } ,false);

        x.send();
    },
    setInfo:function(response){
        this.info = response;

        // if you used the event listeners
        this.request.removeEventListener('load', function(){
            instance.setInfo(x.responseText);
        } ,false);
        delete this.request;

        // this.insertDOM();
        // I just added this for testing purposes only
        document.body.innerHTML = this.info;
    }
};

// added for testing
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var dlTest = new dl("filetoget")
}, false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. 'var instance = this' is a referrer to this which contains alot of stuff and fills up the whole memory.
2.'setInfo:function(response)' i choosed 'this' to have access to every parameter i need without passing it trough a function.
3. 'onreadystatechange' i use 'onload' for testing,because it's short and works perfect on chrome.
4. Your executing instance.setInfo 2 times.
5. You can't remove anonymous functions with removeEventListener

Comment: both my solutions work... but i need to get back the referrer to the new created dl() object inside the onload/onreadystatechange function the proper way.i think binding a function or passing this.that or a instance you did is not a good approach.

Comment: el.addEventListener('readystatechange',f,false) is the same thing as el.onreadystatechange.. except that with evlist.. you can add multiple listeners and also have the appropriate removeEventListener.

Comment: Oh, in that case, you can use `arguments.callee.caller` from inside the dl() function and that should give you the function dl was called from. Or you could find some way to use a callback function of some sort.

Comment: I think that using the `onreadystaechange = function()` looks nicer though

Comment: it's even nicer only writing el.onload=function(){} but the function needs to be a reference and there is no removeEventListener.

Comment: It would say that in the example script because you are calling from an anonymous function, if you cal from a regular function you should get that function. I'll just check

Comment: the function is called by the xhr object and not by me.<- problem ...ASYNC

Comment: Yeah, it seems they took the arguments feature out. Have you thought about trying to use a callback function for whatever your referring back for?

Comment: it's better to use bind before writing comething like this (function(a){return function(){return a}})(this)

Comment: I'll put another answer to show the code that I have at the moment, it doesn't work on JSFiddle.

Comment: like i said both of my examples work... i think bind is not a good solution, i'm not shure how much memory it would use if i create a referrer inside the xhr object or inside the getInfo function. these are the 3 solutions... a fourth would be a even more complicated callback approach.

Comment: Well I'm struggling to think of any other way you could do it and I don't think it would use up that much memory, especially as you are deleting it when the request finishes.

Comment: I know that I have been using callbacks for the exact same type of this and it didn't seem to have any noticeable effect on the running of the code.

Comment: if defining the this object inside the xhr object is the only way and without knowing what happens to the full this referrer a better aproach would be to assign a id to each new dl() and pass that as reference.. at least i know there is only a small number in the memory.but in that case i have to write everything in another way.

Comment: That would work too, except you would have to hold an array of all the dl instances so that you know which one the id refers to, surely that would take up a lot of memory.

Comment: i need to to that in any case... each new dl is a new class execution

Comment: or is it possiple to execute every new dl(url) anonymously?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I mean a separate array, something like `dl.instances = []` then you push each new instance into the array. Why would you need to do that do that in any case?

Comment: var downloads=[];
function addDL(){
 var i=downloads.length
 downloads[i]=new dl(input.value);
}

Comment: inside downloads i have all my info&functions for each dl.

Comment: Yeah, but why would you need that. BTW, you could just use `downloads.push(new dl(input.value))`

Comment: why would you need the info and functions after that request has finished?

Comment: i is reused later and setting a array direct is faster than push. as download lenght is the next aviable position in array ... it's a good way.

Comment: there are plenty of requests in each dl. and every variable is reused/deleted to keep memory low.the first request get's only the file info.

Comment: OK, but off topic how is `.push` slower, if you think about the steps JavaScript has to take, in both situations it would have to find the next position in the array and set the new value to that position. How would it make a difference using `.push` or adding a new position manually?

Comment: As i reuse the array length later i have a variable containing the next index of the array. all i do is to set array[i]=value .. array.push() involves a function execution which is slower.if i don't need the array length push is prolly faster.

Comment: I made a JSFiddle which adds 100000 values to an originally empty array and measured that amount of milliseconds it took to do so. I ran it 20 times and added the results of my tests in the html section. They show that `.push()` is usually quicker, but only by a few milliseconds. http://jsfiddle.net/bM4NW/3/

Comment: Oh, sorry, I only read the last bit of you comment. But, `.push` also returns the new length of the array.

Comment: that just change the same values in the array, your function gets the length and then adds a new value on the end.

Comment: Sorry, it copies the values from one array to another, but that doesn't change the fact that it isn't getting the length of the array like addDL does

Comment: you cant test this case in jsperf..... but array.push(x) is a little slower than array[N]=x because you set it direct.push is a function that does probabily exaclty this return array[array.length]=x.

Comment: why not look at jsfiddle.net/bM4NW/3 it has both methods tested extensivley.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new code:

```
function dl(name, callback) {
    this.name = name;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.getInfo();
}
dl.prototype = {

 getInfo:function(){
  var x=new XMLHttpRequest;
  x.that=this;
  x.open('GET',this.name,false);
  x.addEventListener('load',this.setInfo,false);
  x.send();
 },
 setInfo:function(){
  this.that.info=this.response;
  this.removeEventListener('load',this.setInfo,false);
  //this.that.insertDOM();  
  // when you need to refer back
     this.that.callback(this.responseText);

  delete this.that;
 }   
}

function call() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;

    new dl("filetoget", function (response) {
        console.log(a + b);
        console.log(response);
    });
}

call();
```

Comment: yeah this is basically the code of my second solution.it works ... but what about the refecence created in the xhr object... will it go straigth to the garbage collector or will it end somewhere hidden filling the memory continuosly?

Comment: As far as I know, changing `this.that.callback(this.responseText);` to `this.that.callback(this);` will send a copy of the request, not the actual request. I'll just do a quick test